# How does ListInterpolation work?

Tags: interpolation, implementation-details

[`ListInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListInterpolation.html) takes an array of data and interpolates between the entries.  Let us interpolate between the elements of the identity matrix.  For reference, this is what the identity matrix looks like:

```
MatrixPlot[IdentityMatrix[5]]
```

[image: plot of identity matrix]

Now let's interpolate, and [request first order interpolation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationOrder.html):

```
if = ListInterpolation[IdentityMatrix[5], {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Plot[if[x, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: plot of interpolating function]

The result is a piecewise function as expected, *but not a piecewise linear function*!  Why?  What does first order interpolation mean here?

---

The kind of linear interpolation I am familiar with is what `ListDensityPlot` does:

```
ListDensityPlot[IdentityMatrix[5], DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: ListDensityPlot result]

Construct a Delaunay triangulation of the data and interpolate on each triangle.

This is not what `ListInterpolation` does (or even `Interpolation` when the data is strictly on a square grid).   What does `ListInterpolation` do, then?

---

Inspired by this question:

- [Is there a way to change the interpolation scheme used in ListDensityPlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118474/12)

Comment: Well, it is doing [*bilinear* interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) in your first example, I would think. You definitely will get something with quadratic pieces if you sample across diagonals.

Comment: @J.M. Well, we all have to learn at some point :-)  Yes, you are right, and this is due to my ignorance of math.  But I won't delete it.  If you convert that to a one-line answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Docs say the only methods available to `ListInterpolation` are `Spline` and `Hermite`

Comment: Currently my comment is not that pedagogically useful; I'll try to come up with a sufficiently illuminating example first, unless somebody beats me to it. :)

Comment: @J.M. I got it based on the wiki article, and feeling pretty embarrassed about it now.

Comment: Szabolcs, please consider leaving the question up for a little longer. I was not aware of that behavior either, and I would find it instructive to see an interesting example, if @J.M. or others have the time / inclination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just treat the simplest case of interpolating across four *noncoplanar* points. The extension to general grids is straightforward (one just joins multiple pieces appropriately).

Consider the following bivariate interpolating polynomial:

```
ip[x_, y_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[{{{0, 0}, 1}, {{0, 1}, -1/2},
                                      {{2, 0}, 1/2}, {{2, 1}, 0}}, {x, y}];
```

and the following `InterpolatingFunction[]`:

```
if = ListInterpolation[{{1, -1/2}, {1/2, 0}}, {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

They are the same:

```
Plot3D[ip[x, y] - if[x, y] // Chop, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: flat as a pancake]

Let's have a look at what `ip[]` looks like:

```
Expand[ip[x, y]]
   1 - x/4 - (3 y)/2 + (x y)/2
```

Huh. That last term certainly isn't linear. What gives?

In a *bilinear* interpolation such as this one, although the procedure is something along the lines of "linearly interpolate for each grid line in one direction, and then linearly interpolate those results", the result is inevitably quadratic. This should come as no surprise to people familiar with the [hyperbolic paraboloid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicParaboloid.html), which is one of the simplest examples of a [ruled surface](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RuledSurface.html), or a surface formed by sweeping out a line in space. In fact, `z == 1 - x/4 - (3 y)/2 + (x y)/2` is indeed a hyperbolic paraboloid.

```
{Plot3D[ip[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 - #2 &}], 
 Plot[ip[x, x], {x, 0, 1}]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: hyperbolic paraboloid and a cross section]